# Google datastore ndb.AND vs. and

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I've found that using the ndb datastore API, I can perform a query for something involving multiple properties using something like

```
Entity.query(Entity.p1 == 1 and Entity.p2 == 2)
```

or

```
Entity.query(ndb.AND(Entity.p1 == 1, Entity.p2 == 2))
```

These give the same result, however the second one needs an extra index on properties p1 and p2 to perform the query. Similarly, if you use .filter on the query instead of ndb.AND, no index is needed either. What is the difference between these methods of query datastore?

Answer (score 4):

Be careful; the first version ('and') evaluates to only the second part of the filter. Try this:

```
clause = (Entity.p1 == 1 and Entity.p2 == 2)
print clause
```

=>

```
FilterNode('p2', '=', 2)
```

Doing the following results in the expected filters:

```
clause = (Entity.p1 == 1, Entity.p2 == 2)
```

=>

```
(FilterNode('p1', '=', 1), FilterNode('p2', '=', 2))
```

which is similar to what your second clause using ndb.AND results in ie:

```
AND(FilterNode('p1', '=', 1), FilterNode('p2', '=', 2))
```

(In this case the query results are the same).

As no additional index is required for a single property query you will see no indexes generated for the first query version (using 'and').